# How to load a bean defined without id, name in spring?

Tags: spring

How to load a bean defined without id or name?
Also how will spring differentiate if I have define 2 beans of same class without id or name

```
<bean class="xyz" />
<bean class="xyz" scope="prototype" />
```

it's written that

> Incase there are other bean using the same name, a unique name will be generated

How does spring handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to load a bean defined without id or name?

You can load beans by type:

```
applicationContext.getBeansOfType(xyz.class);
```

The above will return a map from (generated) id to bean instance.

> how will spring differentiate if I have define 2 beans of same class without id or name

If you are autowiring by type, it will throw an exception (two beans of the same type). You cannot autowire by name as there is no name.